# How to properly escape colon in QueryExecute sql statement?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-2016

Update: Not satisfied with this answer but I found that not passing a param struct will cause CF2016 to ignore colons. Looks like CF2018 doesn't have the issue either way (though I can only test that with query of query at the moment).

We have generated sql queries that do not use query params going through `QueryExecute()`. I am sometimes seeing the error **Space is not allowed after parameter prefix ':'** and found it is caused by a string literal with a colon and space. For example:

```
select 'test this: error'
```

I was not able to find an official way to escape the colon and the common escapes didn't work, but figured out this workaround...

```
sqlstring = replace(sqlstring, ": ", ":'+' ", "all")
```

However that doesn't account for other situations that could potentially come up that wouldn't be a string literal such as a column name with colon and space and likely many more I can't think of at the moment.

Is there an official way to escape a colon passed to `QueryExecute` not part of a `queryparam`?

Comment: Newer JDBC drivers support `\:` to escape a colon. If that doesn't work for you, you need to build the JDBC connection manually and send a simple `Statement` instead of a `PreparedStatement`. ColdFusion's `queryExecute`/`cfquery` will always end up as a `PreparedStatement`, so that's not an option.

Comment: I'm running into this too, four years later, except with a question mark instead.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could separate the string out and have it be passed in

```
result = QueryExecute("
  SELECT :mystring AS ...
  ",
  { mystring : "test this: error"}
  );
```

Seems like a lot of work though.